# Flutter and firestore web app - Assertion failed: Map =! null is not true

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-web

I'm trying to create a chart on a Flutter web app by accessing data from Cloud Firestore.

However, it can't seem to extract and map the details from Firestore.

**Firebase console**
[image]

**main.dart**

[image]

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}
```

**home.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:inglesy/items.dart';
import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart' as charts;

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  List<charts.Series<Item, String>>? _seriesBarData; //Try (dynamic,String)
  List<Item>? myData;
  _generateData(myData) {
    print("_generateData worked");
    _seriesBarData?.add(
      charts.Series(
        domainFn: (Item item, _) => item.itemstring.toString(),
        measureFn: (Item item, _) => item.itemvotes,
        id: 'Items',
        data: myData,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("returning AppBar/scaffold now");
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("This is a title."),
        foregroundColor: Colors.pink,
      ),
      body: _buildBody(context),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBody(context) {
    print("Doing _buildBody now");
    final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _userStream =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("poll").snapshots();
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: _userStream,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('Something went wrong');
        } else {
          List<Item> item = snapshot.data!.docs
              .map((DocumentSnapshot document) =>
                  Item.fromMap(document.data() as Map<String, dynamic>))
              .toList();
          return _buildChart(context, item);
        }
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildChart(BuildContext context, List<Item> item) {
    myData = item;
    _generateData(myData);
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text("This is a text"),
              SizedBox(height: 10.0),
              Expanded(
                child: charts.BarChart(
                  _seriesBarData!,
                  animate: true,
                  animationDuration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**items.dart**

```
class Item {
  final String? itemstring;
  final int? itemvotes;

  Item({this.itemstring, this.itemvotes});

  Item.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map)
      : assert(map['itemstring'] != null),
        assert(map['itemvotes'] != null),
        itemstring = map['itemstring'],
        itemvotes = map['itemvotes'];

  @override
  String toString() {
    return "Item string: $itemstring |  Item votes: $itemvotes";
  }
}
```

**It shows this error**

[image]

**PS**, I've already done the necessary set-up i.e. I've already installed Firebase CLI and have it generated firbase_options.dart

**PPS**, I have also already set up Firebase (anonymous) authentication and it works with no errors. But for now, I'm not using it and I'm automatically running home.dart to focus on the Firebase database aspect.

Comment: Hi, Did Roman's answer and comments help you?

Comment: @ZeenathSN Hi. Unfortunately not.

Comment: Have you checked if you are receiving ```null``` for ```itemstring```?

Answer (score 0):

Why don’t you try making the ***Item.fromMap*** method a regular factory method like:

```dart
factory Item.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
 return Item(
   itemstring = map['itemstring'] ?? '',
   itemvotes = map['itemvotes'] ?? ''
 );
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't work 

The following TypeErrorImpl was thrown building StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>(dirty, state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<QuerySnapshot<Object?>, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>>#bd64c):
Unexpected null value.

Comment: I noticed your **poll** collection has an item1, item2, item3, and a question document. Could it be that? Make sure all the documents in your poll collection are following the same schema and format. Can you check whether they all have the same fields and all?

Comment: the question document has a different field. I deleted it so all documents are the same. But when run, it has the same error. :(

Comment: Make sure they all have the same fields and they all have values, otherwise do the quick null check before the mapping, like: itemstring: map['itemstring'] ?? '' to assign an empty string if null. Check the revised code